# Weird situation when retrieving data from sencha datastore

Tags: javascript, extjs, touch

I am having a weird situation when retrieving some data from my datastore. A user can take a walk with my app and save this route. He can save multiple routes if the user wanted to.

I save my coords in a coords store and i retrieve them like this:

```
var coordsStore = Ext.getStore("CoordsStore");
```

first i check if my store has some records:

```
if(coordsStore.getCount() > 0)
```

When true i will loop these through and check the route

```
 for(var i = 0; i < coordsStore.getCount(); i++){

        var model = coordsStore.getData().getAt(i);    
        var routeModel = model.get("route");
  }
```

on the first run this goes how it is supposed to go and returns all records with route 0.

when going for a second run (route 1 in this case) the coords store returns strange values. Instead of expecting also the route 0 coords AND route 1 coords , we only get back the route 1 coords.

What getting my attention is when looking at `coordsStore.getData().getAt(i);`

the data.all contains:

[image]

the data.items contains:

[image]

you see that the route value is different, when using a getAt somehow he is using the values from data.items and not from data.all.

Any Ideas how i can retrieve the data from data.all?

Comment: I usually get the number of elements in a store like this: `coordsStore.count()`

Comment: try store.sync() before checking vals

Comment: @Mr.George Tried it, didnt work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually working with store records i prefer getting them after a load of the store, you should try like this.

```
coordsStore.reload(function(records){ //callback whit records
     records.forEach(function(record,index){
      //you code
    });
});
```

Getting records directly from store object can be a problem, because stores load asyncrounsly.

remember to call a store.sync() to save changes of your store when modifing

Comment: Hi Mr.George, i got it working when using it like this: 'coordsStore.data.all[i]'. But I will try your answer, will be back soon!

Comment: With my code you will be always sure to have new loaded records in the store, good luck! @Red90

Comment: Hi!  your solution works :)  Thank you! Ps. it is btw load not reload :)